# EventLog Path not found

Tags: c#, filenotfoundexception, event-log

I have a simple program designed to send Event Logs when used. I managed to get most of the event logs out of the system, but there are some that throw an Exception (`EventLogException : {"The system cannot find the path specified"}`).

This program works for every file, except the ones with a "%4" in their names (example : *Microsoft-Windows-Wired-AutoConfig%4Operational.evtx*)

The code is the following :

```
EventLogSession Session = new EventLogSession();
Console.WriteLine("Collecting Info started %4");
Console.WriteLine("Creating Temp Folder");
Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Temp");
Console.WriteLine("Acquiring System logs");

foreach (string @item in Session.GetLogNames())
{
    try
    {
         Session.ExportLogAndMessages(@item, PathType.LogName, "*", Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Temp\\" + @item + ".evtx");
    }
    catch(EventLogException EvLgEx)
    {
       { }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Done aquiring logs");
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have a suspicion that you might need to have logic that changes the % into a character that windows allows for filenames.

Comment: Not sure if i follow you there

Comment: Apologies, somehow I thought % was an invalid filename character, which apparently is allowed in a filename. I just ran your code in my environment and everything exported, but I don't see any %4 in any of my event log file names. Any way that we can replicate it?

Comment: I haven't done anything to the Event logs. They are the standard logs in C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs. Mine have a %4 in their name, i dont know why.
My OS is Windows 7 Professional N 64bits, but I have seen those same names in a Windows 8.1 too

Comment: Now I am understanding it. In `EventViewer` those files are the `Protocols`, so the %4 in the filename is actually a / as seen by the `EventViewer` itself. It is however strange that .Net cannot export it. I'll see what I can come up if, if anything

Comment: I have run blank here. All theories I came up with and tried didn't give a result. I am not sure as to how you will be able to export the protocols

Comment: Thank you for the effort anyway.
I am able to copy the logs using the File.Copy() method. The drawback is that i have to copy entire logs, instead of just the entries I want. Using the method above I could just copy the entries neccessary.